# Is it possible to add multiple classes with one toggle event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div with one toggle event that add a class to it and I wanna know if is it possible to add more than one class with classList.toggle

```
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
    navLinks.forEach(navLink => {
      navLink.onclick = e => {
        event.target.classList.toggle('open')
      }
    })
```

This's my code adding a class to the div.

Comment: I think this is what are you looking for 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36544762/vanilla-javascript-is-there-a-way-to-toggle-multiple-css-classes-in-one-stateme

Comment: You can't add multiple classes to the toggle function but you can add multiple toggle functions with different classes.. like ..
event.target.classList.toggle('open')
event.target.classList.toggle('active')

Comment: You are wrong : `classList.toggle()` doesn't simply add a css class, it can also remove it. Your question is unclear!

Comment: @MisterJojo The question seems clear to me: Can `.toggle()` add multiple classes at once.

Comment: @sean no, you are wrong too `.toggle()` can also **remove** a css class ...
and this method accepts **only one CSS class name**, and not "multiple css class names" as you write here in your comment.

Comment: @MisterJojo You're misreading messages. No one has implied it can't remove a class. And I wasn't saying it can accept more than one. I was clarifying the original question was: "Can it accept more than one class name?" which is a clear question.

Comment: @Sean I see that you now accept my point of view: his question is not clear.

Comment: @MisterJojo lol